# I'm having some difficulty understanding Mr. Stroustrup snippet in section 3.3.3 of his new book TCPL 4th edition

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having a problem understanding what the author is trying to convey in section `3.3.3 Resource Management` of his new book `The C++ Programming Language 4th edition`. I copied below the referred section from the author's home page:

**3.3.3 Resource Management** [tour2.copy.resource]

> By deﬁning constructors, copy operations, move operations, and a
>   destructor, a
>       programmer can provide complete control of the lifetime of a contained resource
>       (such as the elements of a container). In particular, a move constructor allows
>       an object to move simply and cheaply from one scope to another. That way, we
>       can move objects that we cannot or would not want to copy out of a scope.
>       Consider a standard-library thread representing a concurrent activity (§5.3.1)
>       and a Vector of a million doubles. We can’t copy the former and don’t want to
>       copy the latter.

```
std::vector<thread> my_threads;
Vector init()
{
    thread t {heartbeat}; // run heartbeat concurrently (on its own thread)
    my_threads.push_back(move(t)); // move t into my_threads
    Vector<double> vec;
    // ... ﬁll vec ...
    return vec; // move res out of run()
}
auto v = init(); // start heartbeat and initialize v
```

> This makes resource handles, such as Vector and thread an alternative
>   to using pointers in many cases. In fact, the standard-library ‘‘smart
>   pointers’’ such as unique_ptr, are themselves such resource handles
>   (§5.2.1). I used the standard-library vector because we don’t get to
>   parameterize Vector with an element type until §3.4.1.

Maybe my question should be: what's the relationship between `vector my_threads` and `Vector vec` inside function `init()`? For instance, what would be the advantage of the code above when confronted with a simpler alternative like the one below:

```
std::vector<thread> my_threads;
thread t(hearbeat);
my_threads.push_back(move(t));
Vector<double> vec;
// ... fill vec ...
```

Comment: *"What would be the advantage of the code above?"* The code is sample code, meant to illustrate operations that were not possible in C++03 that are now possible in C++11, or are more efficient in C++11.

Comment: It gives you an idea of a new trend in c++ programming where returning by value is actually efficient - of course with move semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's the relationship between `vector my_threads` and `Vector vec` inside function `init()`?

Both are illustrations of when you'd want move semantics. In the first case, you can't copy a `std::thread` into `my_threads` (since the class is not copyable), but you can move it. In the second case, you *could* copy an enormous vector in order to return it from the function, but you wouldn't want to because moving is much more efficient.

> what would be the advantage of the code above when confronted with a simpler alternative

The simpler version doesn't demonstrate moving an object out of a function, which is what the author wants to demonstrate.

Comment: It seems to me the author is implying some relationship between `my_threads` and `vec`, specially after reading his last sentence above: `I used the standard-library vector because we don’t get to parameterize Vector with an element type until §3.4.1.` as if he wanted to put both entities in the same `Vector`. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Storing things in the same container type doesn't imply any relationship between those things; we use containers to store all sorts of unrelated things. Presumably, he'd prefer to use the same container for both because he'd prefer to use that container for all his examples. (Although the `Vector` he's using here seems to be parametrised by element type; I guess that was an oversight.)